# MongoDB bulk csv imports (folder full of csv)

Tags: mongodb, csv, import

I have tried to import a single csv file in mongodb using mongoimport using mongoimport -d mydb -c things --type csv --file locations.csv --headerline. It works like a charm. My problem  is that I want to import a folder full of csv(s) in mongodb. I searched, but could not find anything on that. I also tried to give folder path with wildcard (*), but it does not accept that. An example path is /home/user/event_files/* where event_files is the folder containing the csv files. How can I accomplish the import of a folder full of csv(s) in mongodb ?

Thankyou,
Mohsin

EDIT:

```
#!bin/bash
    FILES="/root/event_files/*"
    for f in $FILES
    do
        mongoimport -d mydb -c events --type csv --file "$f" --headerline
    done
```

I made this script to do the job. Replace your own folder path in "FILES" variable. 
In the mongoimport command (between do and done), "mydb" is your database name, "events" is your collection name.
You will need to replace things to suit your needs.

Thankyou,
Mohsin.

Comment: you should post your answer below and accept it rather than EDITING your question.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Loops through the files in event_files and imports each csv using the header line as the data field in mongo.

```
#!bin/bash
FILES="/root/event_files/*"
for f in $FILES
do
    mongoimport -d mydb -c events --type csv --file "$f" --headerline
done
```